# Excel sheet name through jsp

Tags: excel, jsp

suppose I am working with multiple worksheets in an excel file.How do i give a name to each of the worksheet when I am generating the excel file through JSP. I need to generate the file through JSP only.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How exactly does it make difference when you write Java code inside a JSP file instead of in a Java class? (apart from being the wrong place which has only disadvantages with regard to reusability, maintainability and testability). Sure you would be facing the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class, so JSP is irrelevant in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, if you observe you can find a tag

> <x:Name>

under

> <x:ExcelWorksheet>

That is the work sheet name.